# iOS datetime inputs always considered invalid

Tags: javascript, html, ios, datetime

It appears that iOS 10.3.0 or 10.3.1 has completely broken the `datetime-local` HTML input. When a form is submitted, iOS will always consider the input invalid.

When you grab the value using JavaScript, the input returns the date in the following format:
`YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` where "T" is a literal "T," and the second "MM" is the minutes.

If you use JS to set the value to the following format: `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM`, the form can be submitted properly without the "Invalid input" error.

I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cjrqf6r7/) that demonstrates this exact problem, and the solution. You'll need to run it on an iOS device.

The fix is a hacky fix though, and I'm curious to know if anyone else has found a better solution.

Comment: I've also submitted a bug report to Apple.

Comment: Same thing here on three different iOS 10.3+ devices. That's most likely a bug in WKWebView as Chrome seems to be affected as well. I don't think there is an _elegant_ solution to be found here, except for Apple getting its crap together.

Comment: Hi Guys, any updates on this topic?

Comment: The bug still persists until today. Your workaround works, just had to adjust the amount of substring to remove. Thanks.